# Copying file across zip files in python with minimum memory foot print

Tags: python, buffer, zip, memory-mapped-files

I want to efficiently copy a file from one zip file into another with limited usage of memory and disk. Python's zipfile library doesn't support appending to files which is blocking me from doing partial writes.

Questions:

1. Does there exist a python zip library that allows partial file read/write operations?
2. Can I create a buffer interface on top of an open file (zipfile.ZipExtFile) and then pass that to zipfile.writestr?
3. Can I create a in memory file backed by zipfile.ZipExtFile and then pass it to zipfile.write?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can split the zip file in set of parts and then put them together here's an example

> As explained in [O'reilly book Programming Python-By Mark Lutz](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=q8W3WQbNWmkC&pg=PA283&lpg=PA283&dq=Split%20file%20portably%20%20in%20python&source=bl&ots=Y7bidZlv2J&sig=XcgYu4T2b9Kv0_vLiMlqXGhP3Yc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JF8jVbGDJNaTuATdzYDgCw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=Split%20file%20portably%20%20in%20python&f=false)